# Accidentally denied Terminal access to my Documents folder in Jupyter Notebook dashboard

Tags: python, macos, terminal, jupyter-notebook

I'm beginning to learn Python and I installed and started playing around with Jupyter Notebook the other day. I wanted to open and access a file in my Documents folder from the Jupyter Notebook dashboard but when I opened it for the first time, a pop-up window asked me to authorize Terminal to access the folder and instead of accepting, I accidentally clicked "Deny".

As a consequence, the Documents folder disappeared from navigation in the Jupyter dashboard and I can't access it anymore. I tried to `cd`  the Documents folder before running `jupyter notebook` in Terminal and it didn't work either:

```
~ % cd /Users/username/Documents
Documents % jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 254, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 844, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2122, in initialize
    super().initialize(argv)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 230, in initialize
    self.load_config_file()
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 164, in load_config_file
    self.log.debug("Searching %s for config files", self.config_file_paths)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 72, in config_file_paths
    path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Documents %
```

I tried the same thing with other folders (that I authorized access to when opening in Jupyter Notebook instead of denying it) and it worked fine, so it's clearly the consequence of me accidentally clicking that Deny button :(

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Thanks in advance!

P.S. I don't know if it helps but after denying the access, I tried to move a `.ipynb` file into the Documents folder using the "Move" button and typing the folder path and it worked fine, it seems like the issue is reading the folder and not writing in it.

Comment: you need to go to system preferences in the mac settings and check the tick box for terminal https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mchld5a35146/mac

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered in a comment by [python_user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12502959/python-user). Here is the accepted answer:

> you need to go to system preferences in the mac settings and check the tick box for terminal [support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mchld5a35146/mac](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mchld5a35146/mac) – python_user

Comment: glad it worked, you can mark this as a solution

Comment: Privacy & Security > Files and Folders > Terminal, and then toggle the folder you want to give access to